# Unit test new Blob Enzyme for node env

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, blob

I'm trying to test with Enzyme some download function, my test runs in node env. But the method I use is actually dom api, and how to test it in node env. In my code I use `DOM API` like `windows.URL.revokeObjectURL`, `document.createElement('a')` `window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([encodeWorkBook(wbout)], {type:'application/octet-stream'}))`

```
   export const download = (url, name) => {
    let a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href = url
    a.download = name
    a.click()
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}

export const encodeWorkBook = string => {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(string.length)
    const unicodeArray = new Uint8Array(buf)

    for (let i=0; i !== string.length; ++i)
        unicodeArray[i] = string.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF

    return unicodeArray
}

export default (data, sheetName, bookType = OutPutFormats.xlsx) => {
    import('xlsx').then(XLSX => {
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, {cellStyles: true})
        const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new()
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, sheetName)

        const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType, bookSST:true, type: 'binary'})

        /* creates a DOMString containing a URL */

        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([encodeWorkBook(wbout)], {type:'application/octet-stream'}))

        download(url, `import.${bookType}`)
    })
}
```

Comment: *What* are you trying to do in the node environment? Write a file of binary data? There is no "download" obviously.

Comment: @Bergi the main problem here , that I can not use new Blob() in node env, because my test runs in node env. I edited post

Comment: Of course you cannot, but why would you? None of the lines in `download` would work in node either. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I mean, `window.URL`  and `document.createElement` are DOM APIs as well

Comment: @BergiI rephrase the questions, how to test dom API method if test runs in node env?

Comment: Well, just don't - test only the platform-independent functions :-) Your alternatives are 1) use a virtual DOM implemented in JS, like jsdom or cheerio 2) use an actual (headless) browser, orchestrated by the node script

Comment: I use jsdom but got an error `window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function`

Comment: Well yeah, looks like jsdom has not yet implemented that API. Open a feature request - or even better, a pull request with your own patch. Alternatively, use a real browser.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we just need in jsdom  add   `global.Blob = function Blob(params) {return params}`, and stub `window.URL.createObjectURL = sinon.stub().returns(url)`

```
describe('encodeWorkBook', () => {
    it('should encode work book to unicode array', () => {
        encodeWorkBook(workBook).should.be.deep.equal(unicodeArray)
    })
})

describe('exportToExcel', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sinon.stub(XSLX.utils, 'json_to_sheet').withArgs(devices, {cellStyles: true}).returns({})
        sinon.stub(XSLX.utils, 'book_new').returns({})
        sinon.stub(XSLX.utils, 'book_append_sheet').withArgs({},{}, sheetName)
        sinon.stub(XSLX, 'write').returns(workBook)
        window.URL.createObjectURL = sinon.stub().returns(url)
        file.download = sinon.spy()
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        XSLX.utils.json_to_sheet.restore()
        XSLX.utils.book_new.restore()
        XSLX.utils.book_append_sheet.restore()
        XSLX.write.restore()
    })

    it('should call download with correct url and output extension', async () => {
        Object.values(OutputFormats).forEach(async format => {
            await exportToExcel(devices, sheetName, format)

            file.download.args[0][0].should.equal(url)
            file.download.args[0][1].should.equal(`import.${format}`)
            file.download.calledOnce.should.be.true
        })
    })

    it('should call download with default output extension', async () => {
        await exportToExcel(devices, sheetName)

        file.download.args[0][1].should.equal(`import.${OutputFormats.xlsx}`)
    })
})
```